# VB6 Like operator not picking up space character

Tags: regex, vb6

I have a legacy app whereby email addresses are validated using a RegEx experssion passed to VB6 and then compared using the `Like` operator

The RegEx expression is still allowing space characters to be included in the email address which I do not want.

The code below - I want the first to retru  True but the second to return False. What amendment to I need to make to the RegEx expression?

```
Sub LikeTest()

    MsgBox "hello@hello.com" Like "[A-Za-z0-9-\.\]*@*[A-Za-z0-9-\.\].*[A-Za-z]"  'returns True

    MsgBox "hello@ hello.com" Like "[A-Za-z0-9-\.\]*@*[A-Za-z0-9-\.\].*[A-Za-z]"  'returns True but should return False

End Sub
```

Comment: you can use probably a regex like [**this one**](https://regex101.com/r/lW9pF3/1)

Comment: The regexps are not working as you expect since the `]` brackets inside are escaped. Try `"^[A-Za-z0-9-.]+@[A-Za-z0-9-.]+\.[A-Za-z]+$"`. However, I believe you need to use a `vbscript.regexp` object for it to work correctly.

Comment: The [`Like` operator in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) does not, and has never, used conventional regex syntax. It’s using [glob syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). The code you’ve posted has never worked. It’s purely accidental that it does anything at all.

Comment: @shA.t The semantics of the `Like` operator barely changed from VB6 to VB.NET.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes they are same as I checked now but the old link is this link: [`Like` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242817%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) ;).

Comment: IMO You can't use `Like` operator in that way, And I suggest you to use some negative nested if statements instead ;).

Comment: Thanks for your comments all. Unfortunately, this is a legacy app and all I have control over is the RegEx expression passed to the VB6 application

Comment: [How To Use Regular Expressions in Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818802) ;).

Comment: @Mike Long story short, there’s no solution to this problem using `Like`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DIM test
test = LikeTest("hello@hello.com")


Function LikeTest(sEmail)
  RegExpTest = false
  Dim regEx, retVal
  Set regEx = New RegExp

  ' Create regular expression:
   regEx.Pattern ="^[\w-\.]{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,3}$" 

  ' Set pattern:
  regEx.IgnoreCase = true
  ' Set case sensitivity.
  retVal = regEx.Test(sEmail)
  ' Execute the search test.
  If not retVal Then
    RegExpTest = false
  else
   RegExpTest = true    
  End If
  MsgBox(RegExpTest)

End Function
```

Source:

https://web.archive.org/web/20061026092253/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=47

Comment: Don't restrict TLDs to 2/3 characters